# What are the supported RazorLangVersion setting values in .NET 6 and where to set them via Visual Studio UI?

Tags: visual-studio, razor, .net-6.0

I've recently discovered the following line in my few year old project:

```
<RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
```

What are the supported RazorLangVersion setting values in .NET 6 and where to set them via Visual Studio UI?

Answer (score 0):

From this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30329 they try to have it sync with the SDK version. Current latest version should be visible via `dotnet --info`.